# Jqplot - Small pie chart

Tags: canvas, jqplot, pie-chart

I am using jqplot to display graphs/charts.
I want to display a small pie-chart.

So I have fixed the 'height x width' of the div to 100 x 100.
Here's how the pie-chart is displayed.

[image]

There are extra spaces/padding around the pie.
I don't want that. Also how can I remove the canvas from the background. 
Such that only the pie-chart is displayed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [jqplot documentation](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-pieRenderer-js.html#%24.jqplot.PieRenderer.padding):

> $.jqplot.PieRenderer  Plugin renderer to draw a pie chart.
>     **Properties**
>          padding    padding between the pie and plot edges, legend, etc.

Comment: And what about removing the canvas? Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "canvas"?  The border and shadow around the plot?  Look at the properties of the "grid":  http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#Grid.Properties, background and drawBorder would probably help you.

Comment: To remove the background(canvas), you need to set the following: grid: { backgroundColor: 'transparent', drawBorder: false, shadow: false }  This will remove the background and also the shadow of the pie

Comment: can i change size of length of area graph ? ?

Answer (score 2):

To remove the background(canvas), you need to set the following:

grid: { backgroundColor: 'transparent', drawBorder: false, shadow: false }

This will remove the background-canvas(also its border shadow) and also the shadow of the pie.

Hope it helps.